# $firebaseAuth logs me out after refresh (facebook)

Tags: angularjs, facebook, angularfire, firebase-security

I'm using $firebaseAuth to control the login part of my application. Everything worked fine before but now, on refresh, i immediately get logged out.

**Part of my route**:

```
}).when("/login/", {

        templateUrl:"partials/login.html",
        controller:"tiki.controller.login"

}).when("/settings/profile/", {

    templateUrl:"partials/settings.profile.html",
    controller:"tiki.controller.settings.profile",
    resolve:authenticate()

})
```

**The authenticate() function**:

```
function authenticate(){

    return {"currentAuth": ["firebaseAuth", function(firebaseAuth) {

        console.log(firebaseAuth.requireAuth())
        return firebaseAuth.requireAuth();

    }]}     

}
```

**The .run() block that catches a route change error:**

```
angular.module('tiki').run(["$rootScope", "$location", function($rootScope, $location) {

    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {

        // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
        // and redirect the user back to the home page

        if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {

            $location.path("/login/");

        }

    });

}]);
```

**And for completness my firebaseAuth.js service:**

```
'use strict';

/* Services */
angular.module("tiki").factory("firebaseAuth", ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth){

    var ref = new Firebase("https://blistering-xxx.firebaseio.com/");

    if(ref){

        var service = $firebaseAuth(ref)

    }

    function loginFacebook(){

        return service.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook")

    }

    function logOut(){

        service.$unauth()

    }

    function getState(){

        var state = service.$getAuth()

        if(state){

            return state

        }

    }

    function getUserName(){

        if(getState()){

            return getState().facebook.displayName

        }

    }

    function requireAuth(){

        return service.$requireAuth()

    }

    function service(){

        return service

    }

    return {

        loginFacebook:loginFacebook,
        logOut:logOut,
        getState:getState,
        getUserName,
        requireAuth:requireAuth,
        service:service

    }

}])
```

When i refresh in /settings/profile/ i get logged out and returend to /login/.

The console.log() in the authenticate() function returns this:

```
status: 2
value:"AUTH_REQUIRED"
```

This only happens on refresh on all pages. If i don't refresh then the authentication works fine.

Any ideas?

thx,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its your problem, but from:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html

> Optional Settings
>
> authWithOAuthPopup() and authWithOAuthRedirect() take an optional third parameter which is an object containing any of the following settings:
>
> remember
> **If not specified - or set to default - sessions are persisted for as long as you have configured in the Login & Auth tab of your Firebase's Dashboard.** To limit persistence to the lifetime of the current window, set this to sessionOnly. **A value of none will not persist authentication data at all and will end authentication as soon as the page is closed.**

I don't know if a page refresh counts as closing the page, but it might be worth checking the value in Login and Auth to make sure it's not set to something wonky, i just tested and it will gladly let you set it to 0

Comment: Rick, thx for your answer but it seems to have been solved. I didn't change anything to my code so i guess it was a firebase issue of some kind.

Comment: I wish that link still worked. This isn't the only similar guide with broken links so I guess their docs must have updated.